# Using CloudFront only for free Amazon's ssl certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I understand the free ssl certificate is not the main purpose of CloudFront. However, I am just interested what would be the negative sides of that? I am planning to do that with a Drupal website running on ec2 + rds.

I've tried with a dev site and looks like it's working fine with these settings:

> Allowed HTTP Methods - GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
>
> Forward Headers - All
>
> Forward Cookies - All
>
> Query String Forwarding and Caching - Forward all, cache based on all

What could go wrong in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about drupal, but google for "cloudfront wordpress", there're wonderful articles about having static snd dunamic content together, have a look how https://blog.homzit.com works... that's mine :) I believe with it'll be pretty much the same. And I forgot to mention that it works like a charm!

Comment: Yeah, not much articles about Drupal, but a lot about WordPress. However, many of them say I should use some plugins/modules. Would it be possible to avoid using them if I do not need to cache anything?

Comment: You don't need any plugin, it's all just the cloudfront config... the only reasonable plugin there is , is to invalidate the pages automatically... but you can just set an hour of caching or less..

Comment: Awesome :) One more questions: what do I have to change to make CloudFront pass the visitor's IP?

Comment: I had to set it to pass the Origin and the Host for the headers.

Comment: And ... I am lost here :(
Can you please briefly explain how to do that?

Comment: When you set up the behavior in cloudfront for the dynamic pages (like in the wordpress docs mentioned avove) you should pass the Origin and the Host headers... most of these tutorials have images and step by step instructions...

Comment: Super confused. Just one question: is it doable through CloudFront web interface?

Comment: I did it all there... have a look at http://www.danneh.org/2015/04/setting-wordpress-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with your current setup; but we should also consider following:

CloudFront is not free. You will be paying for bandwidth charges.

Also, you don't have to use CF.. Your EC2 instances might be behind ELB ( for high availability) ; and you can use free SSL certificate on ELB also.